# How to solve a Linear Program using the Two-Phase approach?

Tags: linear-programming, two-phase-simplex

> $$\text{Maximize }Z =  X_1 -2X_2$$
> Such that:
> $$3X_1 + X_2 \ge 3$$
> $$2X_1 - X_2 \le 5$$
> $$X_1, X_2 \ge 0$$

I've done it using CET, and found out that $\max(Z)=-6$ when $X_1=0$, $X_2=3$ which is feasible, but I really don’t know how to solve it by Two-Phase method.

Is there anyone who can help me solve this?

Really thanks about that.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

To start, we have the given model:

$$\text{max } z = x_1-2x_2$$

Subject to:

$$3x_1 + x_2 \ge 3$$
$$2x_1-x_2\le5$$
$$x_1,x_2\ge0$$

We’ll need to this into standard form in standard form in respect to the Two-Phase method. However, unlike the standard form of past artificial variable methods like Big-M, we’re going to have to replace the objective function with $\text{min } w = \sum_{a_n} a_n$. Keep in mind that the first phase of the f the Two-Phase method will always replace the objective function with minimizing the sum of the artificial variables as we are trying to make them go to zero, and when we go through the simplex method of this part of the model, if we hit a point where we cannot pivot anymore and all the artificial variables are not zero, then the model is infeasible.

Thus, our model in standard form is this:

$$\text{min } w= a_1$$

Subject to:

$$3x_1 +x_2 -e_1 + a_1 =3$$
$$2x_1 -x_2 +s_2 = 5$$

From here, you’ll solve this via Simplex like you would any other model, and you should get the following tableau:

\begin{array} {|c|c|}\hline BV & w & x_1 & x_2 & e_1 & a_1 & s_2 & RHS & RT \\ \hline w & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & - \\ \hline x_1 & 0 & 1 & 1/3 & -1/3 & 1/3 & 0 & 1 & - \\ \hline 
s_2 & 0 & 0 & -5/3 & 2/3 & -2/3 & 1 & 3 & - \\ \hline  \end{array}

From here, we drop the objective row and the artificial variable column(s) and replace the objective row with the original standardized objective row of our original model. However, we keep the values of everything else in the tableau as such:

\begin{array} {|c|c|}\hline BV & z &
x_1 & x_2 & e_1 & s_2 & RHS & RT \\ \hline z & 1 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & - \\ \hline ? & 0 & 1 & 1/3 & -1/3 & 0 & 1 & - \\ \hline s_2 & 0 & 0 & -5/3 & 2/3 & 1 & 3 & - \\ \hline  \end{array}

From this tableau, make the $x_1$ column basic and proceed like one would with any other model via the Simplex method.

Comment: I think that your use of big-$M$ in two-phase methods is kind of weird, but if you're attached to it, you can continue using it here: just maximize $x_1 - 2x_2 - Ma_1$, or in general subtract $M(a_1 + \dots + a_n)$ from the original objective function.

Comment: I think you might be confused, as the two-phase simplex method uses a separate objective function that minimizes the sum of all the artificial variables in relation to the constraints of the model. It doesn't use, nor need, Big-M and is trying to make it the sum equal to zero. I use the variable $w$ in the above to denote that this is a separate objective function from $z$. However, I do mention Big-M because that's normally what's taught first and what students are more comfortable with and understand. However, my answer does not use Big-M in any way

Comment: However, I do like how you denote $M$ with $M(a_1+\ldots+a_n)$ as that's really pretty! I will use that way if depicting it in the future, thank you!!

Comment: Let me rephrase. The big-M method is a method that is sometimes used to avoid having two objective functions in the two-phase method: rather than minimize $w$ in phase 1 and then maximize $z$ in phase 2, you can combine the two phases and just have a single phase where you maximize $z - Mw$. I noticed you doing this in another solution, but here you said "unlike those situations, we will have to replace the objective function..." so I pointed out a way that you could continue using the big-M method if you wanted to. (I agree you're not using the big-M method in this solution - but you could.)

Comment: Ah, that's a good point! Yeah, I figured it would be simpler, and better if OP would see how it's done the long way and understand that than use clever shortcuts so the process could be better conveyed/understood. However, thank you for pointing this out!!!